# The loop part in the template is not being displayed

Tags: django

template code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Customer Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dear user, please check if the the email list is correct</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for customer in customer_list.objects.all %}
        <li>{{customer.Country}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

view code

```
from practice.models import Customer

class CustomersView(ListView):
    template_name = "practice/customer_list.html"
    context_object_name = "customer_list"


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Customer.objects.all()
```

However, in the code above, pylint underlined Customer and stated "Class 'Customer' has no 'objects' member"

The browser only shows this

## Dear user, please check if the the email list is correct

and not the loop part. I checked the QuerySet, it is not empty.

```
In [1]: from practice.models import Customer                                                                               

In [2]: Customer.objects.all()                                                                                             
Out[2]: <QuerySet [<Customer: Customer object (1)>, <Customer: Customer object (2)>]>
```

What might be the possible causes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `{% for customer in customer_list.objects.all %}` for `{% for customer in customer_list %}`

Answer (score 1):

first of all remove the `get_queryset` method and instead define attribute `model=Customer` - that's the proper way to work with `ListView`. In your case the `get_queryset` override is redundant because you rewrite it exactly as it is when you define model for your `ListVeiw`. Then as the other commented said use `{% for customer in customer_list %}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! Using ```model=Customer ``` also works! I guess this works when we want to get all the objects in the model? I wrote my code my way because I mirrored it to this snippet from the official tutorial.

Comment: ```class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: However, our cases are different. In the tutorial, the code only wants to get the 5 newest objects.  In my case, I want to get all of them from the table. I copied blindly. :(

Comment: Yea it happens to everybody - if you really want to dig into django I suggest reading the source code on github repo after you make your first steps. It really helps in understanding whats going while overriding some methods and also can expand your abilities. For example by reading source code I've learnt how to add personalised message after logging in while extending django's LoginView. Good luck & Cheers mate!

Comment: thanks! I tried to read serve() function source code and had many headaches. My python understanding is to shallow for now.

Comment: Totally understand you mate :) just keep up the good work! I started learning python/django 2yrs ago. Now releasing 3rd commercial app. Good luck!

Comment: congrats! mate!